# How to keep the text on the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to keep the BUY now tag which will be static and the other things will be dynamic. How to keep these things on the img tag?[image: Please see the image i want to do these type of design]

Comment: you can do it with css.

Comment: You can do it after understanding [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/). Unfortunately, any answer here will be just a start point, but with some effort you can do it soon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use the background image a sa DIV background image and position the "buy now" img relatively to that div. Something like:

```
div.buyNow {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 10px;
}
```